# Count duplicated

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine that i have a graph in which for every pair of nodes m,n of type Nod1 there can be a node k of type Nod2 that connect them through relationships of type Rel, that is, there can be multiple patterns of the kind p=(m:Nod1)-[r:Rel]-(k:Nod2)-[s:Rel]-(n:Nod1). For a given node m (satisfying for example m.key="whatever") how can i find the node n that maximizes the number of nodes k that connect m to n? For example: imagine that there are 3 nodes k that connects m to n1 satisfying n1.key="hello" and 10 nodes k that connects m to n2 satisfying n2.key="world"; how to build a query that retrieves the node n2? :)

The title of the question is count duplicated, because i think that the problem is solved if i can count all "duplicated" patterns for each node n (that is, all patterns that has n as "endnode")!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by matching your `m`; then match the pattern you want, then filter by distinct `n` nodes, and count the number of `k` nodes connected via that `n` node, and you should be there.

```
MATCH (m:Nod1 { key: "whatever" })
WITH m
MATCH (m)-[r:Rel]-(k:Nod2)-[s:Rel]-(n:Nod1)
RETURN distinct(n), count(k) as x
ORDER BY x DESC;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This works completely!! I'm wondering how queries in neo4j work. In your query for example i think that second match retrieves all patterns of the form (m)-[r]-(k)-[s]-(n)... when you request to return distinct(n) this acts like a filter in the set of all paterns (meaning that from all patern it must select just those with distinct n)? Sometimes i'm confusing about what set of objects the expressions apply!!!

Comment: another question that i'm in front of right now: supose that each s relationship has a weight. How can i modify yout query to retrieve the sum of weights as well as the distinct nodes? :)

Comment: When you use `distinct` it does what that function suggests, but also has the effect of grouping remaining results by that distinct variable.  If you wanted to sum the weights on a relationship, you'd just use `sum(r.weight)` as a return type.  http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html

Comment: I see....can you try to help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100010/complex-query-with-agregation-in-where-clause ?? Thanks a lot man... :D